# Changing pointer in a loop

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, for-loop

I'm on C++ and the QT IDE:
I want to save the user input of different boxes to an array. I can read the value of the inputbox by this command: ui->h8x->value()

My boxes are numbered like this: h1x, h2x, .... h16x
How can I change the h[i]x pointer in a for loop, is it possible?

```
    for(i=0; i<16; i++)
     {
      array[i]=ui->h[i]x->value();
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`h[i]x` is not a C++ valid syntax.

You should first insert all Qt widgets into a `QVector`, then index them. For example:

```
QVector<QLineEdit *> h;

h.append(ui->h1x);
h.append(ui->h2x);
.
.
h.append(ui->h16x);
```

then you can have this:

```
for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
{
  array[i] = h[i]->text();
}
```

Comment: So there is no way doing this without writing down all names once?

Comment: Yes, there is, you can put those widgets as children of a parent widget. Then, get list of children of that parent, next, iterate over the items and use them. But the simplest way is the code I showed.

Comment: Another way is creating those widget dynamically by coding and store the pointers into a `QVector`